# tab bar controller disappears after modal segue

Tags: ios, xcode, view, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller

I am new to this and really struggling, I have searched on here but the answers to this question don't seem to work with what I am trying

the user selects the store name (button) to present modally a new view controller. but then the tab bar controller disappears, and I cannot get it back. Is there a way to add new view controllers that will always have my tab bar controller? i.e. new "tabs", that will only be displayed if the user decides to push the button regarding that tab. I am using Xcode 6.1 with storyboards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I got it right, but if you want to show a new View Controller and you want to keep showing the tabs you have you should use a NavigationController inside your TabBarController and then do a push, not present modally;

Your storyboard should look like this:

http://timroadley.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/HighLevelStoryboard.jpg

Hope it helps!